# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '*.*.*.*:8000'. You may need to add '*.*.*.*' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django

all.

I have some problem. when i use django.

when i run server as python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000.
and I connect to my page.

but it shows "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '*.*.*.*:8000'. You may need to add '*.*.*.*' to ALLOWED_HOSTS."

I already set the Allowed_hosts =['*'] in the settings.py.

do you know what is problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Django error page prints the value of ALLOWED_HOSTS setting. See what value you get there.

Comment: @serbia99 thank you very much!!